# Bootsrap 4 button toggle menu items to the right...?

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

I have a button (class="navbar-toggler"), which collapses and that works fine, but when I click on it, it displays all the menu items (links) on the left hand side, and it looks terrible!!!

I need to move the menu item links to the right...I've tried everything I could find here...but nothing makes the menu items (links) move to the right...

Can anyone help me solve this?

This is the code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello All</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" datatarget="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "text-right" class on the "navbar-nav":

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello All</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding the class `"navbar-right"` to your nav code

or you can also try

```
margin-left: auto;
```

Comment: Then provide more info to help us answer your question. foe example the css code for the navbar-toggler @ZimSystem

Comment: "Then provide more info to help us answer *your* question".. It's not *my* question, and, as explained, your answer does not work. Edit your answer to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using a menu like pushy? You can have the menu on either the left or right & it's easily changed if needed :)
https://chrisyee.ca/pushy/